# Cannot format a corrupted 32Gb SD card

Tags: sd-card, gparted, corruption

I cannot format a corrupted Sandisk SDHC ULTRA 32Gb micro card.
So I used gparted in an Ubuntu system. I deleted the partition (/dev/sdf1), recreated it and formatted it in fat32. It still keeps its original label and 24% used space.

```
sudo parted /dev/sdf1 unit s print
```

> Model: Unknown (unknown)
>
> Disk /dev/sdf1: 62325760s
>
> Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
>
> Partition Table: msdos
>
> Number  Start End  Size  Type  File system  Flags

```
sudo fdisk -l -u /dev/sdf
```

> Disk /dev/sdf: 31.9 GB, 31914983424 bytes 255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3880 cylinders, total 62333952 sectors
>
> Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
>
> Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>
> I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>
> Disk identifier: 0x00000000
>
> Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
>
> /dev/sdf1   *        8192    62333951    31162880    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdf bs=512 count=1
```

> 1+0 records in
>
> 1+0 records out 512 bytes (512 B) copied, 0.0122556 s,
>   41.8 kB/s

```
sudo shred -vzn 0 /dev/sdf
```

Then I tried to format again (gparted) to get the log info:
[image: gparted info]
[image: gparted log]

```
sudo fsck -a /dev/sdf1
```

> fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
>
> dosfsck 3.0.12, 29 Oct 2011, FAT32, LFN
>
> There are differences between boot sector and its backup.
>
> Differences: (offset:original/backup)   71:33/4e, 72:32/4f, 73:47/20, 74:42/4e, 75:5f/41, 76:47/4d, 77:4f/45   , 78:50/20, 79:4c/20, 80:55/20, 81:53/20
>
> Not automatically fixing this.
>
> Orphaned long file name part"173GOPRO"
>     Auto-deleting.
>
> ........
>
> Free cluster summary wrong (813022 vs. really 744969)
>
> Auto-correcting.
>
> Performing changes.
>
> /dev/sdf1: 417 files, 228615/973584 clusters

```
sudo mkfs.vfat -I /dev/sdf
```

> mkfs.vfat 3.0.12 (29 Oct 2011)

After that, refresh gparted devices takes a long time to display them. Nothing has changed.

So I set two actions: delete the partition and re-created it.
This is the result:
[image: Format 1]
[image: Format 2]
[image: gparted log]

Here's where appears the 'overlapping' info

As suggested in an answer by burlian.vlastimil I tried

http://gparted.org/h2-fix-msdos-pt.php#overlapping-partitions

**$ sudo parted /dev/sda unit s print**

*Error: Can't have overlapping partitions.*

but as you can see above I did not get this error msg for my sdf unit

So, I'm stucked at this point.

Edit 1: in my Mac the card is recognized and it displays the tree of directories and files, correct file sizes and dates.  Before trying anything I described before I could recover some jpgs I needed so I don't care to lose everything

Edit 2: Added some screenshots from testdisk /log

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you post the output of `fdisk /dev/sdf`?

Comment: I recreated the question

Comment: Please post the output of `fdisk -l -u /dev/sdf` and follow @burian.vlastimil's answer. GParted clearly states in your last log overlapping partitions

Comment: It is already in my question, the second command. I already described what happens when started to follow removing overlapping partitions instructions

Comment: What does Testdisk show?

Comment: @eyoung100 
 
I've just installed testdisk. At this time it is analyzing cylinders, very very slow. I added some screenshots to my question. Last one displays an error.

Comment: Let it finish. The disk is reporting the wrong number of cylinders. Once the count is corrected the partitions won't overlap

Comment: @eyoung100 After 15 hours: Analyse cylinder   178/30436: 00%
Read error at 177/1/7 (lba=362534) At the same rate it would take more than 3 months!

Comment: Let it finish... It will speed up after fixing the error, then slow down at other errors etx

Comment: Analyse cylinder  1464/30436: 04% ---
Read error at 1463/1/1 (lba=2996256) --- I've ordered a new card!

Comment: On the `dd` command, why did you use `count=1`? That would only overwrite 512 bytes!

Answer (score 3):

**Can't have overlapping partitions**

The root cause is that the partition table contains at least one occurrence where the end of one partition overlaps the start of another partition.

Source: [How-to Fix Invalid MSDOS Partition Tables](http://gparted.org/h2-fix-msdos-pt.php)

There is also a guide on how to fix it:
[How-to Fix Overlapping Partitions](http://gparted.org/h2-fix-msdos-pt.php#overlapping-partitions)

Comment: I will edit my question to add first step result trying to fix that from http://gparted.org/h2-fix-msdos-pt.php It does not display "Error: can't have overlapping partitions"

Comment: There's only one partition, what is overlapping?

Comment: @dstonek It basically means, that one partition comes partialy over another partition

Comment: Anyway I don't understand why is that. It is a Gopro card occasionally formated in the camera, no partitions handling, just one partition Fat32

Answer (score 0):

Got similar issue on multiple SD who were working in a camera and phones, but won't mount at all on Ubuntu/Mint.

While trying to format, got:

> Can't have overlapping partitions

Wasn't able to format using either **Disks** or **gparted**.

To resolve and mount, step by step:

First make sure you have the necessary packages:

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```

Run the **Disks** gui, to be find in applications.

Note the SD device disk label: (example **/dev/sde**)

Run this command to get the current allocated size:

```
sudo fdisk -l -u /dev/sde
```

Substract the **END** and **START**, example:

`Device     Boot     Start   End       Sectors   Size  Id Type

/dev/sde1  *        8192    15572991  15564800  7.4G  b  W95 FAT32`

So, in this case:

15572991 - 8192 = **15564799**

To edit, write the output on a file:

```
sudo sfdisk -d /dev/sde > sde-bckup.txt
```

Open *sde-bckup.txt* on the home folder with any text editor.

Sample input:

```
label: dos
label-id: 0x00000000
device: /dev/sde
unit: sectors

/dev/sde1 : start=        8192, size=    15564800, type=b, bootable
```

**After edit:**

```
label: dos
label-id: 0x00000000
device: /dev/sde
unit: sectors

/dev/sde1 : start=        8192, size=    15564799, type=b, bootable
```

When done, write back the partition table to the device with this command:

```
sudo sfdisk /dev/sde < sde-bckup.txt
```

If successful:

> The partition table has been altered.

On my case, got the SD card instantly mounted and available on the files explorer.

After that, use the **Disks** utility, **remove all partitions and format with full erasing**. This action is mandatory for later usage. Strangely, when writing datas to the SD with other devices, the issue was coming back again.

Possible causes?

https://www.bunniestudios.com/blog/?page_id=1022

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nuruzFqMgIw

Comment: `When done, write back the partition table to the device:`

When done what?

Comment: An edit had been made. Good luck.